# Get all changed tables from CDC

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

I am polling CDC tables to synchronize data between SQL Server and MongoDB. The approach I have taken is below:

1. Enabled cdc for `dbo.table1` and `dbo.table2` which creates `cdc.dbo_table1_CT` and `cdc.dbo.table2_CT`
2. Created an insert trigger for `cdc.dbo_table1_CT` and `cdc.dbo.table2_CT`. Then the trigger will writes the changed table's name and schema to another table, say `tbl_consolidated_tracks`
3. Then I have a service which polls `tbl_consolidated_tracks` and then from that the service reads the changes and syncs to mongodb

What I am trying to do here is to avoid triggers and the usage of `tbl_consolidated_tracks`.

Can I directly poll the changed tables from any cdc procedure or table?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using triggers on the CDC tables, you should use the built-in CDC functions for returning the changes recorded by CDC. If you only need the latest value for each row, use [cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-net-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but if you need all intermediate changes as well, use [cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-all-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

These functions are created for each table (or 'capture instance') that you enable CDC on and the functions return changes on a table from the earliest LSN to the latest LSN. There is a good article [here](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/analyzing-and-reading-change-data-capture-cdc-records/) that delves into CDC and retrieving the data.

To use it in your periodic polling process, you could do something like this:

1. Fetch the earliest LSN from **cdc.lsn_time_mapping** after the last datetime that you polled.
2. For each table, fetch the max lsn value using **sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn**
3. Use **cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes** or **cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes** with the LSNs from step 1 and 2 to fetch the changes that have occurred since the last polling.
4. Process the changes into MongoDB
5. Log the min and max LSN and the start and end datetime used during this polling to a table. This can be used on the next poll to get the datetime value to determine your next min LSN.

You could even use [SQL Server Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/change-data-capture-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15) which has built-in tools for working with CDC data.

Comment: Get net changes won't be created for tables without PK